# Python 3 does not detect symlinks via stat

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, filesystems

I have run into a weird situation, where it seems different Python modules (`os` and `stat` vs `pathlib`) identifying differently if a file is a symlink or not.

Let's take for example the `python3` binary:

```
paris@pk-tools:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
```

As you can see, based on the shell command above, it's a symbolic link.

If I use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module introduced in Python 3.4, this is being identified as a symbolic link successfully:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('/usr/bin/python3').is_symlink()
True
```

Now, if instead of `pathlib`, I use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) Python modules, the file is not identified as a symbolic link:

```
>>> import os
>>> import stat
>>> st_mode = os.stat('/usr/bin/python3').st_mode
>>> st_mode
33261
>>> stat.S_ISLNK(st_mode)
False
```

I tried this in a Docker Container via Docker for Mac initially, and then in a plain Ubuntu 16.04 and results are the same.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`os.stat` resolves its target. Use `os.lstat` when you want info on the symlink itself.

Here's [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

> `os.stat(path)`
>
> Perform the equivalent of a stat() system call on the given path. (This function follows symlinks; to stat a symlink use lstat().)

vs

> `os.lstat(path)`
>
> Perform the equivalent of an lstat() system call on the given path. Similar to stat(), but does not follow symbolic links. On platforms that do not support symbolic links, this is an alias for stat().